# Writing dates to text file and putting them in order

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that stores user input and puts the date of the input at the start of every line like this:

```
[15 02 2017] [user input] [user input] [user input] [user input]
```

The reason everything is in square brackets is because this is how I read from the text file by splitting. Whatever is in that line is associated with that date.
So anyway when a user wants to make a new entry and chooses to date that entry for lets say the 13/02/2017, I would then like it to appear in the text file in date order instead of just appending to what ever is already in the text file. so it would show:

```
[13 02 2017] [user input] [user input] [user input] [user input]

[15 02 2017] [user input] [user input] [user input] [user input]
```

Comment: You'll find it much easier to do things if you put the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Can you not store the logs in a database table?

Comment: Every time the program starts it puts the contents of the text file in a list view so I figure if the text file is already in date order it just has to add each line to the list view as is. The date format isn't really an issue though.

Comment: @Yawallek using a logical date format would allow alphabetical ordering. KenWhite is right that it would be easier if the date was in that format. I'm unaware of any positive aspect associated with the date format "DD MM YYYY".

Comment: Your log would be much better suited in xml format with serialization/deserialization.

Comment: What if there is already an entry for [13 02 2017], would you want to append the information at the end of the line?

Comment: Why not just append all events at the end of the file, and have the viewer deal with ordering?

Comment: If there is already an entry for the [13 02 2017] then it must just append after that date but obviously not after the 14th or 15th etc. You dealing with an amateur here I know how to loop through each line and add the line and its contents to a listview and its columns but as for putting each line in date order using the dates on the text file I'm not too clued up.

Comment: Keeping the file in a certain order is a rather pointless and needless exercise. How data is stored is of no concern to users. If you read it into the appropriate collection, you can put it in any order you want with 1 line of code. If you step up to serialization, its perhaps easier because you dont have to parse the text file.

Comment: So I changed the format of the date to YYYY-MM-DD and now the listview just automatically displays all the text file info in date order.... I have no clue why, Thanks everyone should have ignored the text file and just worried about the listview.